# Android view onUserVisible event

Tags: android, events

I'm writing some kind of messenger for android, and now I face the problem: I think about  changing message state from unread to read when "Message is visible to user". Message is subclass of `RelativeLayout`, Messages organized into vertical layout with scrolling, which could be long, so I need visible event or something similar.

I found method `void    View.onDisplayHint(int hint)` but docs say

> Applications should not rely on this hint as there is no guarantee that they will receive one.

Any suggestions how to catch visibility to user change?

UPD: layout code if needed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:weightSum="1"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/conversation_main_layout">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutHeader" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/header_background_selector"
        android:padding="3px">
        <Button style="@style/header_button"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:text="@string/conversation_right_button"
            android:id="@+id/buttonCall"></Button>
        <Button style="@style/header_button" android:text="@string/conversation_left_button"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:id="@+id/buttonInfo"></Button>
        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="@string/conversation_header"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/textViewContactName" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_margin="3dip"
        android:scrollbars="none">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayoutDataHolder"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Do I understand you correctly? Your rootView is `ScrollView` with attached `LinearLayout` with vertical orientation which has some `RelativeLayout`s (Messages) lying on it?

Comment: yes, it is. scrollView->LinearLayout(vertical)->RelativeLayouts